# Regex to match email (not strict)

Tags: php, regex, if-statement

I would like to validate if an email address is entered by the user but I don't want to be too strict on it... So I came up with this....

My current if statement with regex:

```
if (preg_match('^/.+?@.+?\..+$/', $_POST["email"]))
```

However, I would not work for an email address with multiple periods...

For example:

```
testing@test.one.com
```

How can I allow multiple `.` or periods?

Comment: You can allow any character multiple times by putting the `+` character after them // `a` = `1 "a" character` // `a*` = `0 or more "a" characters` //  `a+` = `1 or more "a" characters` //  `a{2,5}` = `2 to 5 "a" characters`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest something far simpler that doesn't require you to reinvent the wheel

```
if(filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
```